# To Resize form controls According To Screen Resolutions

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am designing a dotnet Window application which has the resolution 1366x768.I am not able to resize the form controls when the resolution of the screen goes below the given screen resolution.Is there any solution in which I could resize the form controls for lesser resolution also.
So far I have tried the following code. It works well when the resolution is above the given resolution.

```
 private void masterform_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            double RW = (this.Width - CW) / CW;
            double RH = (this.Height - CH) / CH;
            foreach (Control Ctrl in Controls)
            {
                Ctrl.Width += Convert.ToInt32(Ctrl.Width * RW);
                Ctrl.Height += Convert.ToInt32(Ctrl.Height * RH);
                Ctrl.Left += Convert.ToInt32(Ctrl.Left * RW);
                Ctrl.Top += Convert.ToInt32(Ctrl.Top * RH);
            }
            CW = this.Width;
            CH = this.Height;
        }


  private void masterform_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IW = this.Width;
            IH = this.Height;`enter code here`

        }
```

Let me know if any solution exits.

Comment: The trivial way to do this is to simply re-assign the form's Font property with a different font size.  Font is an "ambient" property, controls normally use their parent's font.  Everything gets resized automagically.  Actually creating UI like this is rarely appropriate.  Check how other programs that run on your machine behave when you resize their main window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Table Layout Panel`+`Anchor` to let form handle the size of controls in every resolution.

for doing this you can follow this instruction:

Create a form put a table layout panel, set rows and cols as desired, ***Do not forget*** to set the cols width as `Percent` then put your controls in the cells (or first put a panel into a cell then put your controls on the panel), set the anchors to left+right, and that is it.

See below pictures:

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

Comment: If u have any sample application pls provide.

Comment: Tried this .It is also not working.Am not able to resize the controls still

Comment: @user3541403 If do you mean in design time you have two choice, 1. set Dock of control to Fill 2. Add a panel set it's Dock to Fill then put your controls on Panel and you can change the size of control.

Comment: If i set dock property of a control eg.if suppose for a button ,i am seting dock as fill it is occupying whole form space.I am not able to place any other controls

Comment: @user3541403 First put a panel instead of button then put your button on panel.

Comment: @user3541403 See pictures in answer, also you can put another Table layout panel into a cell.(like button)

Comment: working fine for me after setting dock to panel as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private Size oldSize;
private void Form1_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    oldSize = base.Size;
}
protected override void OnResize(System.EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e);
    foreach (Control cnt in this.Controls) {
        ResizeAll(cnt, base.Size);
    }
    oldSize = base.Size;
}
private void ResizeAll(Control cnt, Size newSize)
{
    int iWidth = newSize.Width - oldSize.Width;
    cnt.Left += (cnt.Left * iWidth) / oldSize.Width;
    cnt.Width += (cnt.Width * iWidth) / oldSize.Width;

    int iHeight = newSize.Height - oldSize.Height;
    cnt.Top += (cnt.Top * iHeight) / oldSize.Height;
    cnt.Height += (cnt.Height * iHeight) / oldSize.Height;
}
```

[description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22780571/scale-windows-forms-window/22781607#22781607)